# Defining a Mongoose schema from a JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I want to define my mongoose schema from JSON file. This is my JSON file structure:

```
   {    
        "default": [
            {
                "item": "productTitle",
                "label": "Product Title",
                "note": "e.g Samsung GALAXY Note 4",
                "type": "text",
                "required": "Product Name cannot be blank..."
            },
            {
                "item": "productCode",
                "label": "Product Code",
                "type": "text",
                "required": "Product Code cannot be blank..."
            }    
        ]}
```

This is my node.js model:

```
// Load the module dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/product.server.model.json';

// Read the json file
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {

data = JSON.parse(data);

var productJson = {};
for(var  i = 0; i < data.default.length; i++) {

    productJson[data.default[i].slug] = {
        type: 'String',
        required: data.default[i].required,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }

}

});

// Define a new 'ProductSchema'
var ProductSchema = new Schema(
   // Here I want to put JSON Data 'productJson'
);

// Create the 'Product' model out of the 'ProductSchema'
mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

I tried every possible way to define mongoose schema from JSON data 'productJson'. But unless I pre-define my mongoose schema, it is not working. Is there any way to define mongoose schema from JSON data in my model? Any suggestion please?

Comment: Aside from `slug` needing to be `item` instead, it looks like that would work if you passed`productJson` to the `Schema` constructor.  What's not working about it?

Comment: If I pass `productJson` to the Schema constructor then an error is showing "productJson is not defined". Because node.js is an asynchronous process. How can I use `productJson` in the `ProductSchema`?

Comment: OK, I didn't see that `productJson` was in the `readFile` callback because of the lack of indenting. So move the schema and model creation inside the callback as well.

Comment: I'm new to the `javascript` world. Can you please explain how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous function which means that it returns immediately and then later provides its results to the caller via the callback function that you provide as the third parameter.

As such, you need to hold off on using `productJson` until its populated within that callback.  That means moving your schema and model creation inside the callback as well.

```
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    var productJson = {};
    for(var  i = 0; i < data.default.length; i++) {

        // Changed .slug to .item here as I don't see slug in the JSON
        productJson[data.default[i].item] = {
            type: 'String',
            required: data.default[i].required,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        }
    }

    // Define a new 'ProductSchema'
    var ProductSchema = new Schema(productJson);

    // Create the 'Product' model out of the 'ProductSchema'
    mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
});
```

Another alternative you can use here is to use the synchronous [`fs.readFileSync`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) method to read the file instead. This is helpful in startup/initialization cases like this where your application as a whole shouldn't proceed until this file is processed.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
data = JSON.parse(data);

var productJson = {};
for(var  i = 0; i < data.default.length; i++) {

    // Changed .slug to .item here as I don't see slug in the JSON
    productJson[data.default[i].item] = {
        type: 'String',
        required: data.default[i].required,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }
}

// Define a new 'ProductSchema'
var ProductSchema = new Schema(productJson);

// Create the 'Product' model out of the 'ProductSchema'
mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Comment: If I do it within `fs.readFile` then an error is showing while I start node server `Schema hasn't been registered for model "Product"`. So please let me know how can I define `Product` model outside `fs.readFile` method?

Comment: @AshikurRahman If you have complicated startup dependencies like that, then it's probably easiest to use `readFileSync` instead.  See the updated answer.