# How to create a Mongoose schema from JSON

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am new into mongodb, nodejs and mongooseJS. Lately, I have been trying to create a mongoose schema for my JSON.

```
{
  "endpoints":["a","z"],
  "poi":[{
  "location_name": "a",
  "latitude": " 10.1075702",
  "longitude": "76.345662",
  "distance" : "0.0"
}, {
  "location_name": "b",
  "latitude": "10.110199",
  "longitude": "76.3489361",
  "distance" : "2.0"
}, {
  "location_name": "c",
  "latitude": "10.1197471",
  "longitude": "76.342873",
   "distance" : "3.1"
}, {
  "location_name": "d",
  "latitude": "10.1254479",
  "longitude": "76.3332626",
   "distance" : "4.4"
}, {
  "location_name": "e",
  "latitude": "10.1443277",
  "longitude": "76.2566017",
  "distance" : "13.9"
}, {
  "location_name": "f",
  "latitude": "10.1487145",
  "longitude": "76.2441114",
   "distance" : "15"
}, {
  "location_name": "z",
  "latitude": "10.145578",
  "longitude": "76.2317077",
  "distance" : "16.9"
}]
}
```

This is my JSON file that I have. I tried using generate-schema from https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema which gave me the following output

```
 { 
endpoints:[ 'String' ], 
poi: [ 'String' ]
 }
```

I used this and when I tested it using Postman from chrome webstore, I was not able to retrieve the complete JSON from the database using the get request. Neither I was able to run a post request successfully.

Recently I tried using JSON schema instead of the mongoose schema using

```
mongoose.Schema("JSON Schema')
```

When I try using JSON Schema I am able to retrieve the data from the mongodb collections using the GET request but I'm not able to POST data correctly with the JSON Schema

I was also thinking about dropping nodejs and redeveloping the webservice in java and mongodb. If I try to use Java web service for interacting with mongodb, is it going to affect the performance of my web app?

Comment: You want to do it on the fly or to make any function to do this stuff?

Comment: I just want to know the mongoose schema that I should be using for my JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a Mongoose schema from a JSON file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859976/defining-a-mongoose-schema-from-a-json-file)

Comment: This is a bug in the library mentioned: https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema/issues/36

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Generate Schemas` module to do this task.

```
var jsonObject={
var GenerateSchema = require('generate-schema')
var schema = GenerateSchema.json('Product',jsonObject);

console.log(JSON.stringify(schema))
```

Since you have two main properties one is `endpoints`
and other `poi`

And here is the output schema of your JSON object

```
    {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "endpoints": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "poi": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "location_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "latitude": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "longitude": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "distance": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> **Suggestion:** You will get some unwanted field and you have to modify it. So I think you should create custom schema on the basis of your object, which would be better for you

You can also get other references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504446/defining-a-mongoose-schema-on-the-fly-from-a-json-formatted-description)

Comment: Thanks I was able to retrieve the data with a couple of customization on the schema you provided. But there are few things that I would like to know. you have answered me with a JSON schema rather than a mongoose schema. In your reference I found details about converting JSON schema to mongoose schema. Which one should I use?

Comment: Now that I have looked through it thoroughly, I am not able to post anything to my web-service but I can retrieve the data with the get request

Comment: If you  customize the generated `schema` and got your valid JSON then you can just pass it in `mongoose.Schema` constructor and that will work..
`mongoose.Schema(your customize schema)`